# Force https for single static html page

Tags: node.js, express

I have set up an express web server and I have it working over https, but I want to add a redirect rule if someone hits my login.html page over regular http.

All my static pages are served using the following rule

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

However, I am having some difficulty figuring out how to make an exception and do a redirect to https for the login page.

I want to somehow intercept the request and redirect if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got your answer from below mentions link.

http://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/redirecting-http-to-https-with-nodejs.html

https://stormpath.com/blog/build-app-nodejs-express-passport-stormpath/